# Windows installer fails with code 1722

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer

I have a Windows installer that fails on a German version of Windows XP, SP3, issuing the code 1722.  The user has run the installer with logging enabled, and the failure occurs when an executable bundled with the installer is run.

The user has tried running the same executable in a command window, both from the directory where the executable is installed and using the full path.  In both cases, the executable succeeded.  FWIW, the user has Administrator privileges.

I've tried running the installer on a German version of Vista; no problem.

I've tried running the installer on (an English version) of XP, using install directories containing spaces and accented characters; no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the \windows\SetupApi.log. You should be able to find more info about the failure there.

Also, with MSI installer you can increase the log level to see more verbose debug output on the failing installation. Check out the MSI command line switches on how to do that.

And, after all, you can use tools like Regmon/Filemon (sysinternals.com) to monitor the installation to see what's going on there

as for my case, there was problem with %TEMP% folder name ...

Comment: The setup log shows which step is failing, but doesn't indicate why.  I've asked the user to try out Process Monitor, which should give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the path to a file that's created at install time contained an environment variable that wasn't being expanded.  We changed the path to the file to use a location guaranteed not to contain such variables.